# Cache pojo field by ehcache in java

Tags: java, caching, ehcache, pojo, in-memory

I want to cache pojo's field in memory(local) and after caching,I want to search by field.For example,here is a basic person pojo.

```
public class Person {
    private final String name;

    public Person(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

For this example, I want to cache by name field and after searching by this field, getting the Person object that contains this name.How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question boils down to "How do I integrate a cache in my application?" This is answered in any cache documentation like in EHCache documentation: [cache usage patterns](http://ehcache.org/generated/2.10.0/html/ehc-all/#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fto-pattrn_cache_usage_patterns.html%23)

Your question should be more specific.

I do not understand your example. What data you want to cache? How do you want to access this data? Is the name unique or can there be many persons with this name?

The cache is also only a volatile storage for speeding thing up. So, what do you use for persistent storage of the POJOs? How do you access and update it?

Your concrete question and example makes no sense. There is no need to cache the name and access it by the name, since you already have it.

Answer (score 0):

As cruftex said, your exact question is hard to grasp, not enough context and a too simplistic example.

However, since I read *cache* and *search*, the below pointers could be of interest:

- [Latest Ehcache Search documentation](http://ehcache.org/generated/2.10.0/html/ehc-all/#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fto-srch_searching_a_cache.html%23)
- [Ehcache 2.8 search documentation](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/apis/search)

But remember that searching on a cache is a solution looking for problems as your cache can evict any entry at any time - base of the cache contract.